# Using Specific words with Speech Input to change background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, speech-recognition

Hello I am creating a mini homepage using a similar code to:

http://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/evsuw

But instead of the words changing the background colour i want it to change the background image and i seem to be struggling abit with it— Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Test</title>
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> </h1>

  
  <span style=" background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/909/flowers-garden-colorful-colourful.jpg");">hi</span>


  <style>
    html,body {
      height:100%;
    }
    body {
      transition:all 0.4s;
      font-family: acumin pro;
      text-align: center;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 50px;
      transition:all 0.4s;
      /*top:50%;*/
      position: relative;
      color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
    span {
      color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      /*text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
      padding:10px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: lowercase;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    var speech  = function(){
      var x = "lol";

      var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.interimResults = true;

      recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        var background-image = event.results[event.results.length - 1][0].transcript;
        // make it lowercase
        background-image = background-image.toLowerCase();
        // strip the spaces out of it
        background-image = background-image.replace(/\s/gi,'');
        $('body').css('background', background-image);

        $('h1').text(background-image);
      }

      recognition.start();

    }

    if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
      alert("Sorry you require a browser that supports speech recognition");
    }
    else {
      speech();
    }
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
   
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using as variable name "background-image". This is wrong in javaScript. Instead of the '-' you have to use the underscore '_' or you can capitalize the next char like:

```
background_image
```

or

```
backgroundImage
```

From MDN:

> Variables
>
> You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.
>
> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>
> You can use most of ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers (for more details see this blog post). You can also use the Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.
>
> Some examples of legal names are Number_hits, temp99, and _name.

Moreover, if you need to strip the spaces you can use:

```
ackground-image = background-image.toLowerCase().trim();
```

instead of regex:

```
background-image = background-image.replace(/\s/gi,'');
```

Comment: It probably needs to remove spaces inside the string as well

Comment: @LarsW It's not an app, it's only a simple demo: one word, trim it, do action. This is the scope of the code.